# JodaTime doesn't recognize some Android timezones

Tags: android, timezone, jodatime

I'm using JodaTime in my app and I'm getting reports from the developer console about crashes like this one:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.myapp.app/Home}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The datetime zone id 'Africa/Abuja' is not recognised
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The datetime zone id 'Africa/Abuja' is not recognised
at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(DateTimeZone.java:337)
...
```

I'm using this line of code to get the Timezone:

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

Interestingly, most of the crashes are `Africa/****`.

`TimeZone.getDefault()` is part of the Android API, so I assumed that it would return usable timezone IDs.

Is there anything I can do with these timezones to be able to use them properly? Is this a known problem with Android and Joda Time?

Comment: I have the same problem with 'America/Toronto'.... Any solution yet?

Comment: @jfcartier No, not really. Since I just need the timezone in milliseconds, I first `try` the `TimeZone.getDefault()` method, pass it into DateTimeZone, and if it throws an exception, I default to using `TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset()` method.

Answer (score 9):

Use this Joda version adapted for Android: https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android

Then, run `JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);` in your Application's `onCreate` (it's in their documentation), and voilà, it *just works*, all timezones are recognized.

Comment: what if I am getting the same problem but on my web application instead of an android app? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The zone "Africa/Abuja" is not a valid time zone identifier in IANA-tz-database using Olson identifiers (named after inventor Arthur David Olson). Instead the valid zone identifier is in this case "Africa/Lagos".

You should also note that JodaTime follows IANA (look for the youngest version there, too) and that Android has a different home-grown tz-database which might use different time zone identifiers. According to this [android-api-link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29) Android supports Olson-tz-identifiers. I am not quite sure why you use "Africa/Abuja" at all resp. why this shall be valid. Is it contained in `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`?

If anything strange in Android configuration causes `TimeZone.getDefault()` using "Africa/Abuja" then you could try to set the system property "user.timezone" to "Africa/Lagos". JodaTime will first look at this property.